# Selectively switch cells in edit row out of edit mode in Kendo Grid

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui

I am using inline editing in a Kendo (MVC) grid.  I have an 'editable' flag to indicate whether in fact a particular cell should indeed be editable.  I'm attempting to use the 'closeCell' method to switch out of edit mode:

On the grid:

```
 .Events(Function(x) x.Edit("onEdit")) _
```

in js:

```
     function onEdit(e) {
//...
         $.each(data, function (i, row) {
                    if (!row.cellEdit) {
                        e.sender._editContainer[0].cells[i].closeCell;
                    }
                })
    }
```

Whilst the closeCell statement is successfully hit no change appears to be made to the cells edit state.  What am I missing?

Comment: Try calling it like `closeCell()`. [Its a method](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid#methods-closeCell), but you're *reading*  it like a property.

Comment: Yes thanks - just spotted that too.

Comment: After more research it seems 'closeCell' is a method of Grid not a cell and is used in doing 'inCell' editing only (where it closes the current, single open cell).

Answer (score 0):

Ok - much more research later I got something to work.  I had been barking up the wrong tree with closeCell() which is for in-cell editing only.

For those that are interested, the desired behaviour can be achieved by iterating through the cells in the row, which is retrieved using the data-uid:

```
 $.each(data, function (i, row) {
            if (!row.cellEdit) {

                var uid = e.container.attr('data-uid');
                var thisRow = $('tr[data-uid="' + uid + '"]');
                var thisCell=$(thisRow).find('td').eq(i);
                thisCell.find('input').prop('disabled', true);
```

This doesn't take the cell out of edit-mode but it does make it read-only which is near enough what I needed.